# WKWebView Not Catch ButtonAction in navigationAction Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

Seems... here we faced an issue.., When a user clicks Button on WkWebview which is not Caught by...

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
// -1 "other" seen when assigning the url programatically
// 0 "linkActivated" a link with an href attribute was tapped
// 3 "reload" page was refreshed
                
 guard let urlAsString = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString else {
     return
  }
               
  if navigationAction.navigationType.rawValue == 0 {
     //***Download Logic here... 
   }  
}
```

But it worked fine previously.

I try to catch the button by its ClassName via injecting js, returns a nil value. Because the WebView loadRequest response rendering in `<iFrame>`

Comment: if u print the `urlAsString` its works ..?

Comment: its means u r activated some link while clicking the button ..?

Comment: Prints urlAsString till didFinish delegate triggers... After that nothing prints... even button click on webview...   
But once webview loadrequest complete... then only, user able to click button. At the same time (while `webview.load(request)`... the `urlAsString` is not fall on the condition 
`if navigationAction.navigationType.rawValue == 0 {
     //***Download Logic here... 
   }`      @Anbu.Karthik